# Loop through array and replace value if in another array?

Tags: php

I am trying to loop through an array and replace values that are in_array of a different array.

```
$array = array("username"=>"Bill", "email" => "Email Address");
$unset = array("Username","Email Address"); // Array of default values for inputs
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    global $unset;
    if(in_array($value, $unset)) {
        $value = "-";
    }
}
print_r($array["email"]);
```

I want to replace the value in $array in which matches a default value to "-". Not looking to unset and array_splice, hold the space.

Comment: replacing $value = "-" with $array[$key] = "-"; works as well.

Comment: you can also use `foreach($array as $key=>&$value)` -- note the ampersand. remember to `unset($value)` after the loop if you do this though, lest you accidentally overwrite the lest element later.

Comment: @Mark I will research more on all this, I am still trying to learn foreach. Thank you for the heads up :)

Comment: the ampersand makes `$value` a reference to the original item in the array. without it you're essentially just editing a copy.

Comment: very good. very good. this foreach stuff has always been confusing to me, but that explanation was very good.

Comment: lest you overwrite the last* element -- made a typo in my earlier comment. the reference is maintained even after the loop terminates, unlike other languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$array = array("username"=>"Bill", "email" => "Email Address");
$unset = array("Username","Email Address"); // Array of default values for inputs

foreach($array as &$value) {
    if(in_array($value, $unset)) {
        $value = "-";
    }
}
print_r($array["email"]);
```

Comment: That also works! I just found that $array[$key] = "-"; works. I will use your method and research a little on it.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be

```
$array = array("username"=>"Bill", "email" => "Email Address");
$unset = array("Username","Email Address"); // Array of default values for inputs
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    if(in_array($value, $unset)) {
        $array[$key] = "-";
    }
}
print_r($array["email"]);
```